# Hadoop architecture with 7 servers - balancing continuity and performance

Tags: architecture, hadoop, hdfs

We're moving off AWS MapReduce to a Hadoop cluster on our own rack. Initially we'll have 7 servers dedicated to Hadoop/HDFS.

The data we store on HDFS will be mission critical, and I don't expect us to have a backup option (at least not on day 1 of our use), so I'd like to do what I can to guarantee continuity.

I'd also like to make the most of our compute power as the jobs we have could easily use double that hardware.

- What should I earmark each box for in this 7-server cluster?  In particular which processes should overlap (e.g. should a backup namenode share a box as a task node and similar?)

Comment: We're going to try using LXC containers to separate the various processes (task nodes, name node, secondary name node, master node) and overlap the name node, secondary, and master nodes with a task node (as these servers all have a large disk and more cpu+memory than the name node or master node needs). We'll use cgroups to guarantee resources to the master and namenodes. I'll answer this question myself in the future when we've tried it out.

Comment: Did you ever get to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we did in the end is this:

Using LXC (LXC is the key component here) we created separate containers on 2 of the servers for the management components such as job manager, namenode, and the various others, since the namenode and job manager are the most resource intensive we split them between these 2 servers (each component in its own separate LXC container). The rest of the components we split between these two servers.

We then deployed a "reduced" datanode and task tracker to each of these two "management" servers. We used LXC's control groups to give CPU and Disk priority to the management components at the expense of the data/task nodes. We used the simplified configuration of Cloudera Manager to easily deploy a reduced number of task slots to the data/task node on these two boxes.

That way we fully utilized the hardware, the rest of the boxes were dedicated "normal" data/task nodes.

We of course had a backup name node running on the same physical host as the job tracker, and the main namenode on the second physical box, this gave us backup. We also installed a use space NTFS client in an LXC container on 3 of the worker machines and had the namenode write out a copy of the configuration there as further backup.

We did loose our namenode to a hardware failure once (disk) and were able to recover it from the secondary successfully.